# Android BLE connects and then immediately disconnects

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been messing with this for the past couple days and I cannot seem to get anything to work the way I want it. I am trying to implement a ble application connecting to a ble peripheral. My app currently works on a Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android version 7.0); however, when I try to run it on my older Motorola Droid Turbo (Android version 6.0.1) the ble connection sometimes connects but almost always ends up disconnecting at some point before I am done doing what I need to do. In most cases it connects and then immediately disconnects. In the rare instances when it does connect (and stays connected) it inevitably disconnects when I am sending information to the peripheral.

```
03-26 15:05:57.563 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: B8:27:EB:CC:E7:AC, auto: false
03-26 15:05:57.564 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
03-26 15:05:57.564 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=c218af9a-b54f-484f-8860-3c9a6b9ed430
03-26 15:05:57.567 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: requestConnectionPriority() - params: 1
03-26 15:05:57.568 14379-14391/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
03-26 15:05:57.818 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
03-26 15:05:57.834 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/LOG: Stopping ble scan
03-26 15:05:57.837 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
03-26 15:05:57.837 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
03-26 15:06:38.282 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=B8:27:EB:CC:E7:AC
03-26 15:06:38.283 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy I/BluetoothLeService: Connected to GATT server. s:0
03-26 15:06:38.284 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: B8:27:EB:CC:E7:AC
03-26 15:06:38.284 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/LOG: Inside ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED
03-26 15:06:38.288 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy I/BluetoothLeService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
03-26 15:06:39.168 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=34 clientIf=6 device=B8:27:EB:CC:E7:AC
03-26 15:06:39.169 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy I/BluetoothLeService: Disconnected from GATT server. s:34
03-26 15:06:39.171 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: close()
03-26 15:06:39.171 14379-14393/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
03-26 15:06:39.172 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy D/LOG: Inside ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED
03-26 15:06:39.174 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy W/BluetoothLeService: BluetoothAdapter not initialized
03-26 15:06:39.174 14379-14379/com.agilepq.devel.apqproxy I/BluetoothLeService: onUnbind() - intent unbound.
```

The only way I have seemed to be able to get it to even kind of work is to insert `Thread.sleep()` methods anywhere from 500 to 3000 milliseconds after each ble action.

Someone informed me that it doesn't seem to work on OnePlus Two either, running I believe Android verison 7.1.2 but haven't confirmed.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be the case? Maybe just something I have overlooked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the hci snoop log, an air sniffer log, or the btmon log from the Pi?

Comment: @Emil Here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_qOQ5HSOoQtCNi5G677HnwjKz-jYaQK5/view

Comment: If you open it in Wireshark you can see that the "Read Remote Version" request never succeeds. It seems like the remote device doesn't respond and your phone therefore times out with the "LL Response Timeout". To investigate this issue you could use an air sniffer to be able to see the actual Link Layer Control Protocol packets. But it seems either your phone's Bluetooth chip or the Pi's Bluetooth chip misbehaves.

Comment: @Emil So I have tested it on a different Pi and tested again with my S6 and the Droid Turbo but still getting the same errors on the Turbo. Would I be able to rule out the bluetooth chips on each Pi misbehaving?

Comment: I would assume the Turbo misbehaves because I haven't seen this problem earlier for a Pi. But you need to use an air sniffer to really verify the issue.

Comment: I don't have one right now and am only able to debug with I have at the moment. But is it possible the s6 doesn't disconnect properly resulting in a bad connection for the Turbo?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But in that case the Broadcom chip inside the RPi has buggy firmware.

Comment: I just tested it with another s6 yesterday and everything thing seemed to work perfectly. So improper disconnections don't seem to be the issue. Still trying to figure this out.